# Calculating Processing time for a Mule flow by using Interceptors

Tags: java, mule

I want to calculate the execution time which my mule flow takes for execution,so I have used interceptor for it,
here is my interceptor code

```
    class CustomLoggerInterceptor extends AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor {
       @Override
      public MuleEvent last(MuleEvent event, ProcessingTime time, long startTime,
        boolean exceptionWasThrown) throws MuleException {
             long totalTime=time.getStatistics().getTotalProcessingTime();
             LOG.info("Start time for flow: "+event.getFlowConstruct().getName()+" is: "+startTime+" total execution time is: "+totalTime);
             return event;
       }
       //other inherited methods

    }
```

now the problem is,whenever I execute my mule flow all the value I get from `time.getStatistics().getTotalProcessingTime()` is always '0'.

Am I using the correct method or I have made some mistake?

I basically need a way to find execution time from `ProcessingTime` object.

Any pointers appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by following 2 ways :-

1) By using a **timer interceptor** :-

```
<timer-interceptor />
```

Put this at the end of your flow

2) Use **custom interceptor** to create your own **timer interceptor** :-

Use this at the end of the flow :-

```
<custom-interceptor class="com.customInterceptor.TimerInterceptor" />
```

and com.customInterceptor.TimerInterceptor class :-

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.interceptor.Interceptor;
import org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

/**
 * <code>TimerInterceptor</code> simply times and displays the time taken to
 * process an event.
 */
public class TimerInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessor
        implements Interceptor {
    /**
     * logger used by this class
     */
    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(TimerInterceptor.class);

    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        MuleEvent resultEvent = processNext(event);

        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            long executionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            logger.info("Custom Timer : "+resultEvent.getFlowConstruct().getName() + " took "
                    + executionTime + "ms to process event ["
                    + resultEvent.getId() + "]");
        }

        return resultEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: that sounds good.. just one query if I use `timer-interceptor` then does it automatically log the result in Mule-console for a particular flow?because I want the time taken along with its flow name,as my application has multiple flows and I want time logging for every flow

Comment: In that case you can do it following way:- If you just use `timer-interceptor` tag in Mule flow you can put a logger just before the  `timer-interceptor` and use expression like :- `#[flow.name]` to get the flow name in console

Comment: I tried executing using timer-interceptor but everytime it returns me 0ms, but in case of Other approach it gives me some value as System time is used in it..Is there something I have missed in timer-interceptor?

Comment: Put at the end of the flow .. Both approach are same .. if you use **timer-interceptor**, it will use Mule default java class at background... where as if you are using **Custom interceptor** you are using same class that Mule uses at background during **timer-interceptor**.. but only thing is that you can customize the class , it's loggers etc in your own way

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary I think the timer-intercept should be used at the beginning of the flow in case you want to measure the processing time taken by a message in the flow, if you use place it at the end it will show something close to zero always.

Comment: @Sudarshan I guess at the end the timer interceptor will display the total time taken by the flow to reach that point where the interceptor is placed. You can try and explore placing it in different position in the flow :)

Comment: Does someone know how to add category to the custom interceptor logger? something like the category provided by the Mule loggers, I need to add category="com.company.flowName

Answer (score 1):

I can't advise to use an AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor for two reasins, it's not part of the public API and they don't do exactly what you want, as per:

```
EnvelopeInterceptor is an intercepter that will fire before and after an event is received.
```

Have you considered using [server notifications](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications)?

Comment: Hey Victor, out of curiosity, just wanted to know what do you mean by "it's not part of the public API", from where can I get this information which says  these classes/interfaces are part of public APIs and you can use while doing customization

Answer (score 1):

I made the same test because I wanted to calculate the processing time of a flow.

Here it's the example:

```
package com.testing.interceptor;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor;
import org.mule.management.stats.ProcessingTime;

public class CustomInterceptor extends AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor{

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CustomInterceptor.class);


    @Override
    public MuleEvent last(MuleEvent event, ProcessingTime time, long startTime,
      boolean exceptionWasThrown) throws MuleException {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        logger.info("Flow:"+event.getFlowConstruct().getName()+"-Procesing Time:"+(endTime-startTime));
        return event;
     }

    @Override
    public MuleEvent before(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {

        return event;
    }

    @Override
    public MuleEvent after(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {


        return event;
    }
}
```

And this is the flow:

```
<flow name="testingFlowClient">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/client/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <custom-interceptor class="com.testing.interceptor.CustomInterceptor" />
        <logger message="Before Transformation" level="INFO" />
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.testing.domain.GeneralRequest" />
        <set-variable variableName="processTypeJob" value="#[payload.processTypeJob]"/>
        <set-variable variableName="waitTime" value="#[payload.waitTime]"/>
        <logger message="After Transformation" level="INFO" />
        <json:object-to-json-transformer/>
        <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/service/{waitTime}" method="POST" 
                        responseTimeout="50000000">
            <http:request-builder>
                <http:query-param paramName="api_key"
                    value="abcde" />
                <http:query-param paramName="processTypeJob" value="#[processTypeJob]" />
                <http:query-param paramName="fields" value="averages" />
                <http:uri-param paramName="waitTime" value="#[waitTime]" />
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
    </flow>
```

Notice that I calculate the processing time by using the "startTime" parameter of the "last" method, and I place the "custom-interceptor" element at the beginning of the flow.

This is the printed log:

```
2015-12-10 18:21:27,493 INFO [com.testing.interceptor.TimerInterceptor] - Flow:testingFlowClient-Procesing Time:341
```