# How long does it take to process a request

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have created a flow in anypoint studio with a http endpoint, how can I know the time in MLS it takes to process the request meaning from the time it starts the flow until the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by following 2 ways :-

1) By using a timer interceptor :-

```
<timer-interceptor />
```

reference :- https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/using-interceptors

2) Use **custom interceptor** to create your own timer interceptor

You can find following reference here :- [Calculating Processing time for a Mule flow by using Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857901/calculating-processing-time-for-a-mule-flow-by-using-interceptors)

Comment: it worked for me to add the `<timer-interceptor />` at the beginning of the flow, thanks! +!!