# date operations in mule esb using data weave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have requirement like where need to find difference in between two dates using dataweave, Both input and output is XML format.

both the date formats are yyyy.mm.dd and output date format must be like mm.dd.yy or mm.dd.yyyy.

Please assist me, thanks

Comment: You may wanna consider the Java solution instead, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857901/calculating-processing-time-for-a-mule-flow-by-using-interceptors

Answer (score 1):

You can format dates like this (example):

yourInputDate as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})

you can add and subtract dates, another example how i use this in a project with variables:

```
%var stamp = (now as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"})
%var dayDiff = ("P" ++ (stamp.dayOfWeek - 1) ++ "D") as :period
%var firstDateWeek = (stamp - dayDiff) as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

docs here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-types#datetime

Answer (score 1):

In Dataweave, you can convert a string to date format and then just subtract them

**Input**

```
<dates>
   <startDate>2007.05.01</startDate>
   <endDate>2017.02.15</endDate>
</dates>
```

**Transform**

```
%dw 1.0
%var startDate = payload.dates.startDate as :date {format: "yyyy.MM.dd"}
%var endDate = payload.dates.endDate as :date {format: "yyyy.MM.dd"}
%output application/json
---
{
    difference: startDate - endDate
}
```

**Output**

```
{
   "difference": "P9Y9M14D"
}
```

9 years, 9 months, 14 days

Comment: Hey Abhay, I also got the same output :) but here output date format(difference) must be mm-dd-yyyy or mm-dd-yy

Comment: Like 09-14-09 for 9 years, 9 months, 14 days? explain a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global function with Java/Groovy and use DateTime object to find the difference and return from that function. Now you can use that function inside your dataweave.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two Dates in dataweave. Format the date according to your requirement

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  a: |23:59:56-03:00| - |22:59:56-00:00|,
  b: |2003-10-01| - |2002-09-23|
}

{
  "a": "PT-4H",
  "b": "P-1Y-8D"
}
```